# Make the latest changes from the GitHub repository are reflect in docker containers

Tags: docker, ubuntu, github, docker-compose, docker-image

I work on Docker image locally, every time I make any changes I push it to Github.

I have Docker container running on my Ubuntu DigitalOcean server, and it uses that image directly from Github.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
 node-api-a:
    build:
      context: git@github.com:BasselTurky/bluekiwiapp-repo.git#main:api-image
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - SSH_PRIVATE_KEY={MYKEY}
    image: node_api_image
    container_name: nodeApiA-con
    network_mode: host
```

When I push a new update to Github, I take down the containers with `docker-compose down`, then I start it again with `docker-compose up -d`

When I do that, Docker doesn't show any changes made but uses the old image again.

How can I make Docker always build a new image? (or detect if any changes made then create a new one if so, this will be more efficient)

Comment: You can do a `docker pull your_name/node_api_image` between `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up -d` to update the image on your Digital Ocean server.

Answer (score 0):

As Docker uses cached images when building the containers.
When you push a new update to Github and up the containers again, docker will use the previously fetched image.

You can run

```
docker-compose build
```

before `up` your containers. `docker-compose build` will re-build the image with latest updates.

or

you can use the `--build` flag with `docker-compose up`

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

`--build` will instruct the docker compose to build or rebuild the image